# Looping over all files except for a certain type

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm creating a batch file that encrypts files to a different folder, I'm however only able to do it with .txt files at the moment using

```
FOR %%c in (%myDir%\%1\*.txt*) DO (
...
```

I however want to do it for all files except for files ending with .aes
is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all the `.aes` files before executing the for loop and then unhide them back.

```
ATTRIB +H *.aes
FOR %%c in (%myDir%\%1\*.txt*) DO (
...
ATTRIB -H *.aes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%c in (
  'dir /b /a-d "%myDir%\%1\*.txt*" ^|findstr /l /i /v /e "\.aes"'
 ) DO ( echo "%myDir%\%1\%%c"
)
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an option:

```
@echo off
FOR %%c in ("%myDir%\%1\*.*") DO (
   if /i not "%%~xc"==".aes" (
      echo "%%c"
   )
)
```